# Functions CancelIO() and GetOverlappedResult() are missing from win32 api

Tags: visual-c++, windows-mobile, smartphone, cancelio

I cannot find the function CancelIo and GetOverlappedResult

The function CancelIO is described as
The CancelIO function cancels all pending input and output (I/O) operations that were issued by the calling thread for the specified file handle. The function does not cancel I/O operations issued for the file handle by other threads.

The function GetOverlappedResult is described as
Retrieves the results of an overlapped operation on the specified file, named pipe, or communications device. To specify a timeout interval or wait on an alertable thread.

They are not defined in the windows.h.  where header file can I find them?  or are there equlivlent function can replace them?

Comment: Both [GetOverlappedResult()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683209(v=vs.85).aspx) and [CancelIO()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363791(v=vs.85).aspx) are supposed to be pulled in with `#include <windows.h>`. They're actually in headers like `WinBase.h` that are pulled into `Windows.h` Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 require `#include <ioapiset.h>` for `GetOverlappedResult()`, but I'm surprised `Windows.h` doesn't pull that is as well.

Comment: I just checked they are not in winbase.h either.  I am running my application under win32 smart device Visual 2008 environment, it that makes any difference

Comment: It likely will (make a difference), since if you're targeting Windows CE (intentionally or otherwise) overlapped IO isn't supported, which would explain the lack of API support.

Answer (score 1):

Windows CE, the base OS beneath Windows Mobile, doesn't support overlapped I/O.  You'll have to re-factor the code to eliminate its use.